# No USB boot. No CD boot. Can I install Ubuntu on a Mac Mini?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, virtualbox, uefi, mac

I've been through the answers to similar questions, but they all require USB or CDROM booting. I've installed EFI - it might be that I've not done that correctly, but it boots in EFI, but doesn't find the CD or a USB stick.

I have got Ubuntu running under VirtualBox on the mac mini. It's just horribly slow.

Is there not some way that I can install bootable Ubuntu onto another partition on the same physical drive, so I can dual boot from the same disc, using Ubuntu on VirtualBox?

I've been hunting, but I can't find any instructions to do this.

I'd be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a way to do this, that I have found. I have installed many, many versions of Ubuntu on various computers. You will need a CD, or USB to do this. You cannot start an install of an OS while working in an OS due to the r/w process. You will have to boot from an external device like CD or USB. If you get your hands on a USB stick I recommend using Rufus to create the bootable USB device.